# starting a python script via crontab on OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, cron

I have a working python3 script and I have setup the crontab via crontab -e. I have added this line

```
* * * * *  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 /Users/harvey/PycharmProjects/3_5_pgm/3woerter.py
```

The cron is executing the script, but I get an email with this error message:

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=harvey>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=harvey>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/harvey>
Message-Id: <20161221161003.1BE13ABFDD0D@harvey-Mac-Pro-4.local>
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 17:10:03 +0100 (CET)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harvey/PycharmProjects/3_5_pgm/3woerter.py", line 43, in <module>
    website("http://www.krone.at/nachrichten/rss.html")
  File "/Users/harvey/PycharmProjects/3_5_pgm/3woerter.py", line 25, in website
    fobj_out.write(str(titleSoup))           # <--- in Ausgabedatei schreiben
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 121: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I think cron is using python2 not python3
When I'm trying the command direct via terminal, all works fine.

How can I ensure, that cron is using python3?

Comment: What is the output if you issue the full command via terminal?`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 /Users/harvey/PycharmProjects/3_5_pgm/3woerter.py`

Comment: Then I get the output from my scrip and my bot as posted a tweet as it should.

Comment: So the problem is not actually with the crontab. You could edit the question to be [solved] or fill in your answer below. The UTF encoding issue  is worth a new question, but be sure to search SO first because I am pretty sure that is comes up all the time.

Comment: @AlexGRice: No, forget all my comments regarding the UTF-8 encoding. It's still the issue of cron, because when I'm starting the script in terminal via python with the same command as it is in crontab I get no error and everything works fine. if I'm starting the command in terminal via python3  with the same command as it is in crontab I get no error and everything works fine. But when cron is starting the job I get the ascii error

Comment: sorry, I can't edit my comment.  I have deleted my old wrong comments.

Comment: hope this info will help: under System//Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions the "Current" folder points to 2.7 and there is no 3.5 or 3.6 version. I think that's the reason why cron uses python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too! I solved this by adding `LC_ALL` and `LANG`:

`LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.utf-8
* * * * *  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 /Users/harvey/PycharmProjects/3_5_pgm/3woerter.py`

Which I learned about reading http://click.pocoo.org/5/python3/#python-3-surrogate-handling for another problem earlier